# What causes Visual Studio to reload projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Our team has a solution that has 15 projects that we all work on collaboratively using git for source control. Sometimes when switching branches Visual Studio simply updates the source files and the branch switch takes seconds(bounded by how fast I can type commands).

Other times though, when switching branches, Visual Studio will popup a dialog saying that it needs to reload all the projects and then I have to sit and wait for approximately five minutes while Visual Studio goes through this process.

I'm guessing that something we're doing with line endings is causing us to touch one of the Visual Studio specific files, and that causes the reload, only I'm not sure which one, or if that's even the right path to go down.

So my specific question then is, "What causes Visual Studio to need to reload projects?"

Comment: +1 for the frustration this can cause. I end up closing the solution before I switch branches - but that means waiting for VS to unload ~20 projects ... then load them again once the branch switch has finished.

Comment: Modification of the `.*proj` or `.sln` file will cause VS to request a full project reload. Can't think of any other files which would cause it off the top of my head

Comment: Are the references in the project files exactly the same? If the project files are being committed then it will create this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact it is quite easy:

Every file change will cause Visual Studio to reload the file, whether it has really changed, or not.

*When changing a project file, it will reload the entire project.*

Maybe git, or some other software, is updating some attributes of the file (so not the content). This might trigger the 'Visual Studio' file change monitor already. I have the same issue using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I think the OP is specifically referring to a modification of an *entire project*, rather than re-loading individual source code files

Comment: Nope. If I modify a file outside VS it will ask me to reload that file alone. If I modify, for example, my `.csproj` file I'll be asked to close/reload the entire project.

Comment: @RGraham: Now I got the confusion. Clarified the answer. Thanks.